# C# wpf Как изменить область выделения Item'а?

Tags: c#, wpf, графика

В программе имеется ListBox, итемы которого представляют из себя Шестиугольники(получается сетка). Panel Item'a - Canvas. Можно ли сделать, чтобы элемент становился выбранным, только если кликнуть по фигуре(по шестиугольнику), а не по области вокруг неё? А то они друг друга перекрывают, это неудобно. Это нужно изменять Border или как-то по другому?

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate" TargetType="ListBox">
            <Border Name="Border">
                <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                        Focusable="false">
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
           
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="CanvasPanel">
            <Canvas></Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Polygons}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource CanvasPanel}"  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow}" Template="{StaticResource ListBoxTemplate}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Polygon Stroke="Black" Fill="Aqua" Points="100, 0, 200, 50, 200, 150, 100, 200, 0, 150, 0, 50"></Polygon>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding StartPoint.Y}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding StartPoint.X}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Область вокруг фигуры должна быть без фона `Background="{x:Null}"`, а не с прозрачным фоном, тогда на нее нельзя будет кликнуть. Подробнее не увидев разметки не скажу.

Comment: @aepot Добавил код разметки